# How I can give the names of 3D matrix dimensions using dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensor

I want to give the names to the 3D matrix from a list I already have. I can only able to give one side a name but not to other 2 sides.

As mentioned in the code, I am only able to put one side, but I want to put names of 3 different sides.

```
subjects_in_graph = ['C', 'c1', 'c2']
edges_in_graph = ['p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1'] 

df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in matrix], keys=subjects_in_graph)
print (df)
```

expected result

```
        C   c1   c2    
C  p1  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0  

c1 p1  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p2  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p3  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p4  1.0  0.0  0.0  

c2 p1  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p2  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p3  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   p4  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

actual result

```
        0    1    2    
C  0  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   1  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   2  0.0  0.0  0.0  
   3  0.0  0.0  0.0  
c1 0  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   1  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   2  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   3  1.0  0.0  0.0  
c2 0  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   1  1.0  0.0  0.0  
   2  1.0  0.0  0.0 
   3  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `index` and `columns` in `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=edges_in_graph[::-1], columns=subjects_in_graph) for x in matrix], keys=subjects_in_graph)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         C   c1   c2
C  p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
c1 p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
c2 p1  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p2  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p3  0.0  0.0  0.0
   p4  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 77, in Main_Graph
    df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=edges_in_graph[::-1], columns=subjects_in_graph) for x in matrix], keys=subjects_in_graph)
  File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 77, in <listcomp>
    df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=edges_in_graph[::-1], columns=subjects_in_graph) for x in matrix], keys=subjects_in_graph)
NameError: name 'edges_in_graph' is not defined

This is an error I am getting

Comment: `edges_in_graph` is the variable name you posted in the question :P You can of course substitute it with `['p4', 'p3', 'p2', 'p1'] `

Comment: >Yes I know its a list name as I mentioned but when I run the code it give me this error even I change the places of index and with colums >df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=subjects_in_graph, >index=edges_in_graph) for x in tensor_new], keys=subjects_in_graph)
>print(df)

>Now it shows this error : NameError: name 'subjects_in_graph' is not defined

Comment: Order of keyword argument doesn't change anything. Make sure your script has indeed a variable called `edges_in_graph`. You can try putting `print(edges_in_graph)` before the `pd.concat(...)` part.

Comment: I did all but this is the output now:  ['p4', 'p1', 'p3', 'p2'] 


   class Main_Graph:
  File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 81, in Main_Graph
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=edges_in_graph, colums=subjects_in_graph) for x in matrix])
  File "M:\Eclipse\hey\Main_Graph.py", line 81, in <listcomp>
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, index=edges_in_graph, colums=subjects_in_graph) for x in matrix])
NameError: name 'edges_in_graph' is not defined

Comment: I even try this having the same error

a = ['C', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4', 'e5', 'e6']
b = ['p3', 'type', 'p1', 'p4', 'p2']
print(a)
print (b)
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=b, index=a) for x in matrix])
print(df)